# Navigation not working as expected in WinJS

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

Ello!

I have an app bar icon and on the click event - I added a function which has the following code:

```
function homePage() {

    WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/home/homePage.html");

}
```

Now I have two files - homePage.html which is inside /home/ and the js file for the same.

There's a simple button on html of id NextPage.

While in the homePage.js file, I have:

```
function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/home/homePage.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
           var button = document.getElementById("NextPage");
           button.addEventListener("click", GoToNextPage);
        }
    });
    function GoToNextPage() {
        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/default.html");
    }

})();
```

But when I click the app bar icon - nothing happens :(

So what I plan to accomplish is that when someone clicks an appbar icon on default.html - the user switches to homePage.html (and then when I click the homePage button - it goes back) - but not even the initial page transfer is taking place.

This is embarrassing to ask but I can't just fold my hands and wait for something magical to happen. I have been working on this for an hour - read videos and samples but it's not working at all.

Would appreciate help - I can't figure out what's going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If you step into the .navigate call in VS, what happens? If you follow it all the way down, does it fail anywhere? Are you including homePage.js in the HTML document that you are calling .navigate in?

Comment: Hey. Yep, homepage.js is in the head src of the homePage.html. Navigation isn't occurring actually - I don't get any error :(

Comment: Is homePage.html the start page in the manifest? Your JS file needs to be included in the start page of your application (or, more specifically, the page *from* which you are initiating the navigation.

Comment: It's in the default.html (homepage) too (from where I initiate navigation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `WinJS.Navigation` namespace provides state and history management, but it doesn't actually do the navigation itself. To move from one page to another, you need to define a handler function for one of the events in the `WinJS.Navigation` namespace - this lets you respond to call to the `WinJS.Navigation.navigate` method in a way which makes sense for your app.

As a demonstration, here is a `homePage.html` file which has a NavBar containing a command that will be the trigger for the navigation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>NavProject</title>
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/homePage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="contentTarget">
            <h1>Select a page from the NavBar</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" 
        data-win-options="{placement:'top'}">

        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
            data-win-options="{id:'NextPage', label:'Next Page', 
                icon:'\u0031', section:'selection'}">
        </button>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Along with the NavBar, I have defined the `div` element whose `id` is `contentTarget`. This is the place in my content where the new file will be loaded when the user clicks the NavBar command.

CLARIFICATION: All of the content that you want replaced needs to go into the `contentTarget` element. Otherwise you'll get a mix of old and new content displayed.

And here is the JavaScript file which wires it up (this is the `homePage.js` file which I added a script element for in the HTML file above):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.Navigation.addEventListener("navigating", function (e) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("contentTarget");

        WinJS.UI.Animation.exitPage(elem.children).then(function () {
            WinJS.Utilities.empty(elem);
            WinJS.UI.Pages.render(e.detail.location, elem)
                .then(function () {
                    return WinJS.UI.Animation.enterPage(elem.children)
                });
        });
    });

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());

        navbar.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if (e.target.id == "NextPage") {
                WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/nextPage.html");
            }
        }, true);

    };
    app.start();
})();
```

Notice how I have added a handler function for the `WinJS.Navigation.navigating` event. This event is triggered by a call to `WinJS.Navigation.navigate` and details of the navigation target are contained in the `detail.location` property of the event object.

In this example, I clear out any content in my target element and replace it with the contents of the target file and animate the transition from one to the other.

You only have to define one handler for the event. This means that if I have elements in `nextPage.html` that will lead to navigation, I just need to call `WinJS.Navigation.navigate` without needing to create a new event handler, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/nextPage.html", {
                ready: function () {
                    back.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/homePage.html");
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is next page.
        <button id="back">Back</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Adam..a small confusion: the JS file you mentioned is HomePage.js right? Do I not have to program anything in the js portion of the file I am navigating to?

Comment: That's right - nothing is needed in the file you are trying to get to. (I added a sentence to the answer to make that clearer)

Comment: Alright. So it partially works lol. It shows the new page (Translucent) on top of the current default.html and animates to the left and kind of disappears..how do I fix this?

Comment: OK - from your question, I thought you had replaced default.html with homePage.html. You will need to define the NavBar in default.html and move the navigation event handling code to default.js. I'll update my answer in a second

Comment: In my case, yes default.html is homePage.html :) and I am navigating from default to homePage (nextPage in your case). I have defined navbar in default and the navigation events in default.js. So yeah pretty much done all that.

Comment: Everything works..it's just that the newPage.html comes on top of default.html and animates to the left.

Comment: And have you added the div element into which the content will be loaded in the default.html file? (The one whose id is contentTarget in my answer)

Comment: Ah - all of the content in default.html must be placed inside the contentTarget element (except the NavBar, of course).

Comment: Hey Adam. When I try to go back: I get this error: " JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'children' of undefined or null reference" Any clue why is that?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you are trying to go back - the error suggests that there are no child elements in the contentTarget element. Without being able to see your code, it is hard to know - but as stab in the dark, make sure that you are going back by calling WinJS.Navigation.back or by calling WinJS.Navigate.navigate to get to a new URL. If you remain stuck, zip up your project and put it somewhere I can download it from and I'll take a quick look.